# Wso2 API Manager : Soap Service | How to Default SoapAction

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to set default SoapAction value for a soap service configured on wso2 api managaer 2.1.0.

[image: API Store - soap service Api console]

For Soap services we do not have option to edit swagger definition:
[image: Publisher-APiDefinition]

please advise how do i default the value of soap action, in our scenario it is not relevant. if there is way to remove from ui and set default value for all api call that would also work. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's SOAP 1.2 you can simply ignore Soap Action.

If it's SOAP 1.1, you can have a custom mediation sequence and set `SOAPAction` http header like this.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="admin--sample">  
      <property name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" expression="YourSoapActionHere"/>  
 </sequence>
```

If you want to modify the UI, you'll have to tweak this file.

```
repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/api/swagger/swagger/swagger-ui{.min}.js
```